# need to handle session time out using promises ($q) in Angularjs application

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I am trying to convert my existing jquery Ajax request to use Angularjs Promises. I am not able to figure how to include fail condition in my promises. Except that remaining things are working fine.

Earlier I had my jquery Ajax call as shown below. Here when I make an Ajax in case of session time out etc, I used get alert message defined in ajaxSissionTimeOutHandler().

```
function getUserList() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "oar3ajax.do",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action: 'getUserDetails',
             postMessage : parameterToSend,
            lanes : filterCrtArg.subs
        },
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(originalRequest) {
        var res = originalRequest;
        if (res == null) {
            alert("Sorry...There was an error retrieving the Data.");
        }
        if (res.ResultSet.status == 'failure') {
            alert(res.ResultSet.error);

        } else {
            /* Code to be Executed  */
        }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        ajaxSissionTimeOutHandler();
    });
}

function ajaxSissionTimeOutHandler() {
    alert("You have been logged out due to inactivity");
    window.location = "/";
}
```

The following is my converted code using Promises :

In services.js :

```
this.getUserDetails = function() {

        var originalRequest = $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "oar3ajax.do",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                action: "getUserDetails"
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });

        return $q.when(originalRequest).then(function(res) {
            if (res.ResultSet.error) {
                return $q.reject(res.ResultSet.error);
            } else {
                return res.ResultSet.Response;

            }
        });
```

And in controller.js :

```
var userPromise = DataService.getUserDetails();
userPromise.then(function(data) {
    var indataToRefresh = data.tabDetails[0].columns;
}, function(error) {
    alert(error);
});
```

Here also when I make an Ajax call in case of session time out etc, I want to get alert message similar to the one defined in ajaxSissionTimeOutHandler(). How can I define it?

Comment: You are mixing both the worlds. use the `$http` service instead of $.ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use `$.ajax`, use angular's `$http` instead. Then it would look something like this (not tested, but you should get the idea):

```
// earlier, include $http in your service function
// e.g. angular.module('yourModule'). service('yourService', function($http) {
// note that angular uses json by default
this.getUserDetails = function() {
  return $http.post('oar3ajax.do', {action: "getUserDetails"}).success(function(response) {
    // do something with your data
  }).error(function(error) {
    // do something with the error
  });
});
```

Your controller can be the same. `$http` already returns a promise, so you can just use `return $http.post`. If you want to process your data, before the promise is resolved in your controller, you could do sth like this:

```
// earlier, include $http and $q in your service function
// e.g. angular.module('yourModule'). service('yourService', function($http, $q) {
// note that angular uses json by default
this.getUserDetails = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.post('oar3ajax.do', {action: "getUserDetails"}).success(function(response) {
    // do something with your data
    // then resolve
    deferred.resolve(response);
  }).error(function(error) {
    // do something with the error
    deferred.reject(response);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
});
```

Comment: I need to send many parameters too which I have not put in my original sample code. Now I have edited the question. So in {action: "getUserDetails"} can  I included the other parameters too in http as I am doing my  edited sample code?

Comment: Yes you can include as many parameters as you want, for example `{action: "getUserDetails", someMoreData: [1,2,3], foobar: "blub"}`